# Deny the logical sentence $(∀x)((p(x)→q(x))∨q(x))$

Tags: discrete-mathematics

I need to deny a logical sentence. However, I don't have extensive knowledge of denial, so I don't know if my resolution makes sense. So I'd like someone to review my resolution and say if it makes sense.

**Q:**
Deny the logical sentence $(∀x)((p(x)→q(x))∨q(x))$

**What I tried:**

To negate the "for all" I will have to use the "exists.

$(∀x)((p(x)$

To:
$(∃x)((p(x)$

The negation of the implication connective will be the conjunction connective, followed by the negation of the variable q.

$→q(x))$

To:

$∧¬q(x))$

The negation of the disjunction connective will be the conjunction connective, plus the negation of the variable q.

$∨q(x))$

To:

$∧¬q(x))$

So:

$(∀x)((p(x)→q(x))∨q(x))$

Is
$
(∃x)((p(x)∧¬q(x))∧¬q(x))$

If anyone can analyze and say if I made any mistakes, I appreciate it. I'm still new to discrete math, I always have some doubts.

Comment: Your bottom line is correct, but your argument is a little confused/confusing, because you are trying to break the problem down in to subproblems that involve things like $\exists x((p(x)$ and $\to q(x)$ that are not well-formed formulas. It would be better to say that he negation of $\forall x (A)$ is $\exists x (\lnot A)$. Then if $A$ has then form $B \lor C$, its negation is $\lnot B \land \lnot C$ and so on.

Comment: For what it's worth, the shortcut is to realize that the original statement, which you are trying to negate, has a redundant trailing clause.  That is $p(x) \implies q(x)$ will automatically hold, whenever $q(x)$ is true.  So adding the trailing clause $\cdots \vee q(x)$ does not alter when the overall assertion is true.  Therefore, when trying to negate the original assertion, you can pretend that the trailing clause is not there.